# debugging shows that all items in checkbox list as unchecked when there are 3checked

Tags: vb.net, checkboxlist

so im dynamically populating a checkbox list. I have confirmed that my text and values are correct for each checkbox but when I check a few and click my event button when I loop through the items they are all set to select=false...

```
    Dim resource As ListItem
    Dim SelectedHashTable As New Hashtable
    For Each resource In chkResources.Items
        If resource.Selected = True Then
            SelectedHashTable.Add(resource.Text, resource.Value)
        End If
    Next
```

set checkpoint at line 5 to view contents of hash table but it is never triggered. Even when I check all boxes. Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you dynamically populating the checkboxlist?  If it's any time after the `OnInit` event, then the control's viewstate is not getting saved properly and your selections will be overridden on every postback.  Try dynamically populating your list in the `OnInit` handler.

Comment: thanks I totally forgot about that issue! put it in a isPostBack check and all is well :D